# How to register custom functions add in with different view in excel

Tags: visual-studio, office-js, custom-functions-excel

I was trying to run the sample project with custom functions add-in using this link: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Excel-Custom-Functions.

I made sure that I meet all the prerequisites for running the project. I installed the certificates, and run the project successfully, but I'm stuck at step 3, of registering the custom functions add-ins by going to the insert tab and adding the respective add-in by selecting from the developer section. The problem I'm facing is that I have a different view and organization of options in my excel client application and I could not find the developer section from where I can register my Add-in. I'm attaching the images of the ribbon that I have in excel.

So if you will look into the images, you will see that there is manage my addins options, which will only show the add-ins that have been sideloaded manually but not the ones that were sideloaded using the script in this project. So I don't know where can I find the developer Section. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm also part of the Insider program which can be seen in the given image
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed my problem after I found out that custom functions only works with the Insider Channel and not with Monthly Targeted, which I had beforehand. I got help from this link: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/create-custom-functions-in-excel-is-not-working-as/1ce500cc-8f83-421a-bb7c-2ae34027d444.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a member of the **Office Insider** program and are running Excel for Windows build number 10827 or later, the **Insert** ribbon should look like the following screenshot (with red rectangles highlighting the items you choose to register your custom functions add-in).

- Have you joined the [Office Insider](https://products.office.com/office-insider) program?
- What build number of Excel for Windows are you running?

[image]

(Screenshot taken from the [Custom Functions Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-tutorial-custom-functions)).